# Weird issue: "t" key ignored (JBoss development with ICEfaces)

Tags: javascript, jboss, icefaces

I inherited a JBoss project from a co-worker. It is a chat client which uses ICEfaces and it works mostly fine... but it has a very strange problem: the user cannot enter a "t" into the input area. Uppercase "T" works fine, and you can copy/paste a "t" into the textarea, but for some reason it does not recognize when the user presses the "t" key.

I have no idea what could be causing this. I have searched the code for anything that captures keypress or keydown events, but there is only one function, which only does anything special for keycodes 13 and 116, not 84.

To make things even weirder, the problem manifests itself on IE and Chrome, but not Firefox.

Does anyone have any idea of what could be happening? Where should I start looking?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Without any code, it is very hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found a solution.

The problem was that I was using onkeypress, and the letter "t" has the same code as "F5" (116 instead of 84) for the key press event. I changed it to onkeydown and that fixed the problem.